# Vertical space in tabularx with imported MnSymbols

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, tabularx, mnsymbol

I am using the `memoir` package with TeXMaker on Windows 7. I would like to create a table (unsing `tabularx`) in which I explain the symbols that I will be using throughout my document. The symbols themselves are imported from `MnSymbol`. I *do not* use MnSymbol math characters throughout, but just import the few symbols I need in the preamble.

Now, for some reason, using these `MnSymbol` characters in a `tabularx` environment introduces arbitrary vertical space in my main document like so:

[image: Examplme of misaligned last column, with symbols.]

Why? What throws me is that, when writing a MWE for this thread, the misalignment disappeared! Here's a snapshot of the MWE.

[image: And suddenly, the misalignment disappears.]

I have not modified the definition of the `table` environment in my main `memoir` document. I have tried replacing the `MnSymbol` macros I've created with their 'plain' commands, which did not resolve the issue.

Could someone help?

*Minimal Working Example*

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Import symbols from MnSymbol:
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\medstar}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medlozenge}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{197}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleup}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{81}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}} 
     Letter & Caption & Number & Symbol\\
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}\\
    A & first line & $1.00$ & $\medstar$ \\
    B & second line & $2.00$ & $\medlozenge$ \\
    C & third line & $3.00$ & $\medtriangleup$ \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hrulefill}
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Here's a basic table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows no misalignment, as testified by this code, where I add `\showbase` to the first cell in order to mark the baseline:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\showbase}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height 0pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}}

% Import symbols from MnSymbol:
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\medstar}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medlozenge}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{197}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleup}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{81}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\showbase}c*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}} 
     Letter & Caption & Number & Symbol\\
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}\\
    A & first line & $1.00$ & $\medstar$ \\
    B & second line & $2.00$ & $\medlozenge$ \\
    C & third line & $3.00$ & $\medtriangleup$ \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hrulefill}
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Here's a basic table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if I change the first table row into

```
    A & first line & $1.00$ & \color{blue}$\medstar$ \\
```

I get

[image]

which indeed shows the issue. It is precisely caused by `\color{blue}` starting the text. If the input is the correct

```
\textcolor{blue}{$\medstar$}
```

the problem would not appear.

So the issue is not linked to using symbols imported from `MnSymbol`, but just to improper usage of `\color`.

Note that your tricks for making a rule or leaving space in the table are wrong.

Here's a working code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
Letter & Caption & Number & Symbol\\[1ex]
A & first line & $1.00$ & \textcolor{blue}{$\medstar$} \\
B & second line & $2.00$ & \textcolor{green}{$\medlozenge$} \\
C & third line & $3.00$ & \textcolor{red}{$\medtriangleup$} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Here's a basic table.}
\end{table}
```

I suggest using `booktabs` anyway.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's instructive. Thanks, the difference between `color` and `textcolor` completely eluded me. Do you have an idea why, not changing my previous usage of `color`, I managed to align my entries just by adding the `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` in the preamble? 
(Also, for reference, I did switch to `booktabs`. Thanks for the recommendation.)

Answer (score 1):

Your table "construction" is quite unusual. And `MnSymbol` is not source of your problem.

Its not clear what you like to achieve with `\multicolumn{4}{c}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}\\` .  Instead this I will rader use some of rules from package `booktabs`, for example `\addlinespace` for increasinf space between rows, `\midrul` fro line between column headers and rest of columns and `bottomrule` for line on bottom of the table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % added 'booktabs', removed 'tabularx' since it is provided by memoir

% Import symbols from MnSymbol:
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\medstar}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medlozenge}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{197}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleup}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{81}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
     Letter & Caption & Number & Symbol\\
%     \addlinespace   % it is not clear, if you like to have more vertical space
    \midrule          % or line as I selected here
    A & first line & $1.00$ & $\medstar$ \\
    B & second line & $2.00$ & $\medlozenge$ \\
    C & third line & $3.00$ & $\medtriangleup$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Here's a basic table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Zarko. I did resort to using `booktabs` for introducing vertical space and lines, rather than butchering some piece of code together.
However, that did not solve my problem. For some reason, my main `memoir` file still 'staggers' my right column.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat shamefully, adding `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` in the preamble combined with Zarko's answer solved my problem. Hopes this'll help others too.